# Номер версии APK должен быть больше... — не дает опубликовать в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Ранее, спокойно обновлял своё приложение в Google Play - всё проходило быстро и без проблем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот очередной апдейт, при загрузке APK-файла получаю такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А где он задается этот номер версии для Google Play ? 
С номером версии моего приложения он естественно не совпадает как видно - да и должен ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `build.gradle` есть строка versionCode. При каждой новой публикации нужно увеличивать значение. Значит вам нужно просто поменять значение **55** на другое.